# Showing previous $_GET results when pressing back

Tags: php, session, get

I have a table controlled by a dropdown box. My dropdown for example has all animals, lion, crocodile, and wolf. When I press lion results show fine, I then click crocodile and again results are fine but when I click the browser back button I can no longer see the previous results. What I want is after I click crocodile to be able to click the browser button and it to show previous results from the lion I clicked here is my code so far: I have also tried storing as local storage to no avail. The session is collected and posted onto a separate page that filters with this dropdown code. Bottom session code is what will display into a table.

```
<form id='id' method='GET' name='myform'> 
<!--<select name='fetching' class='filter' id='fetching' onchange = "getSelectValue()">  -->
<select name='fetching' class='filter' id='fetching'> 
    <option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Select option </option> 
    <option value='All'>All</option> 
    <optgroup label='rare'>
    <?php
    $s = "SELECT DISTINCT species,status from animal"; 
    $result = $con->query($s);
    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $s)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($row['status']=='rare'){
                    $output = "<option value='".$row['species']."'";    //keeps select option on dropdown the same upon page refresh
                    if($_GET['fetching'] == $row['species']){
                         $output .= " selected='selected'";
                    }
                    $output .= ">".$row['species']."</option>";
                    echo $output;
                    if($_GET['fetching']){
                        // $output .= " selected='selected'";
                        $_SESSION['animal'] = $_GET['fetching'];
                        header("Location: room.php?pn=1"); //added 12.04.22
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if (($_SESSION['animal']) =='lion') 
{
  $result = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT * FROM `animal` WHERE species='lion' and gender='female' $limit"); 
}
    ?>
```